# Beginning with Eclipse Tycho

Tags: eclipse-rcp, maven-3, tycho

I have a maven application that I'd like to convert to Eclipse RCP. My application has a large amount of dependencies that are currently specified in the POM.

I am not sure how to deal with this large amount of dependencies.

Would Tycho help for instance?

Can I use my existing POM with all its dependencies or do I have to specify them in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches in tycho. The first is the manifest-first approach where you define your dependencies in the manifest. Tycho reads in the manifest and resolves the dependencies from the target platform. So you have to define the dependencies in the manifests and create a target platform from your dependencies.

The second approach is the pom-first approach, where you define all your dependencies in the pom. I don't know, if this is usable already, because the tycho team started with the manifest-first approach. You should have a look at the tycho docs, if there is an example for the pom-first approach.